# Semi-transparent sprite not transparent after passing through a fragment shader

Tags: c#, .net, shader, sfml

I'm using SFML.net 2.1.
I've successfully implemented a fragment shader that changes the color of a sprite depending on the team color.

[image: Example color change]

However, when I set the color of the complete sprite to a semi-transparent color

let's say RGBA(255, 255, 255, 100)

The resulting sprite is not semi-transparent as expected, but stays fully opaque.
My code works if I comment out the shader, but doesn't work as soon as the shader active.

[image: The image is not transparent!]

Here is my shader code, in case that may be the problem:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

uniform vec4 sourceColor;
uniform vec4 targetColor;

uniform float tolerance;

void main()
{
    // lookup the pixel in the texture
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);

    if(abs(pixel.r - sourceColor.r) < tolerance && abs(pixel.g - sourceColor.g) < tolerance && abs(pixel.b - sourceColor.b) < tolerance)
    {
        gl_FragColor = targetColor;
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = pixel;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Upon further investigation, it seems that the whole Color field of the object is not taken in consideration when drawing the object, not only the alpha channel

**Edit2:**

I've found a workaround for this problem by passing the current color to the shader each frame. However, I'm very interested to know how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

are you actually setting the values as integers like that?

Instead of (255,255,255,100), try (1,1,1,0.4)

Comment: SFML actually auto-converts the value to the correct format. That's not the issue, but thanks for replying

Comment: If that's the case I would check state variables, outside the shader. Perhaps alpha is being masked? Are you set to the right composite mode?